# Makefile: print shell output

Tags: meteor, makefile

How can the output of a remote command in a Makefile be locally printed? The Makefile is called on my local laptop. It connects to my server and do the meteor build. The build is done but without visual feedback. Now I want the output of the build script (the script itself delivers output) be printed in my local terminal as well. But how?

```
PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    @ssh my-server \
        "cd ~/.tmp/source/ ; \
        meteor build ~/.tmp/build --directory --server-only --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 ; \
        "
```

Comment: If `meteor` sends output to standard output then you should see that on the local terminal. Does it do that? (Does it perhaps detect that it isn't connected to a terminal and run "silently"?)

Comment: try redirecting output to your terminal add `>&1` at the end after the quotes

Comment: otherwise you can also redirect to file and scp the file to your laptop.

Comment: Does `meteor` output what you want if you do your build in a terminal after sshing ? Does it still output if you type yourself "ssh my-server "cd ... metero build .." ?